# How to understand "of" in "She is a woman of enviable beauty."

Tags: prepositions

I found It's hard to understand the word **of** in some sentence which I gotten when I was checking the word **of** from an online dictionary.

A sort of explanation about **of** the dictionary given are shown below:

> You use **of** to indicate a characteristic or quality that someone or
>   something has.

And the dictionary also showed some examples:

> the worth of their music.

According to the explanation given above,I suppose this sentence would means **their music has a quality of worth**.

> the creaminess of her skin

I suppose this sentence would means **her skin has a quality of creaminess**.

So far the explanation works properly.

But,

> She is a woman of enviable beauty.

I can't understand this one ,because I can't suppose it means **the enviable beauty has a quality of a woman**. It looks weird if I simply using the explanation to understand it.

And I also can not understand this one.

> A matter of overwhelming importance

Source:http://www.iciba.com/of

**the worth of their music** means **their music has a quality of worth**. But **a woman of enviable beauty** means **Enviable beauty's qualities are had by a woman**.In other word,it means **a woman has a quality of enviable beauty**.so **noun1 of noun2** seems sometimes means  **noun1 has a quality of  noun2** ,and sometimes means **noun2 has a quality of  noun1** .

Are noun1 and noun2 exchangeable?

Taking an example:

Do **the worth of their music** and **their music of the worth** have the same meaning.

Thanks.

.

Comment: You are overthinking things.  "You use of to indicate a characteristic or quality that someone or something has" explains it.  She is a woman **who has** enviable beauty.  The matter **has** overwhelming importance.  That's all.  Nothing more complicated than that.

Comment: Just like _the creaminess of her skin_ means "her skin has a quality of creaminess," _a woman of enviable beauty_ means "her beauty is enviable." In other words, other women might envy her, because of her beauty. Similarly, _a matter of overwhelming importance_ is simply "a very important matter."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this is partly due to the confusing examples [the dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american-cobuild-learners/of) gives. The reason behind this seems to be that, when listing senses, the dictionary only focuses on the meaning, not the grammatical use of the word.

I think it's useful if you stick to this: in a noun phrase like this one, **whatever comes before *of* is what we want to talk about**.

Let's have a look at the first two examples:

> The worth of their music

We want to talk about the *worth*, which comes before *of*, not the *music*. Although using *of* here lets us know that "their music has the worth," we are not talking about the music itself.

> The worth of their music has decreased in the last few years

What has decreased here is the *worth*, not the *music*.

Likewise,

> The creaminess of her skin

talks about the *creaminess*, which is a quality of *her skin*, but not the skin itself.

Now, for the other examples

> A woman of enviable beauty

Remember, we want to talk about the thing that comes before *of*, so here we want to talk about a *woman*, not the *enviable beauty*. It just tells us the quality, i.e. the beauty, of the woman.

The same goes for

> A matter of overwhelming importance.

Here, what is talked about is a *matter*, not its importance.

---

**Note**: I know I actually *cheated* when writing this answer, because these are, at least in my opinion, examples of two different uses of *of* (one is a complement, another a modifier.) For a more technical explanation on this matter, see Huddleston & Pullum (2002), page 439 and 446.

However, I believe it is important to keep things simple, and describing it this way, while not perfectly accurate, works most of the time for learners. If anybody wishes to write a more technically accurate answer, that would be great as well.

Comment: I would add "A woman whose beauty is enviable" as a translation with the same meaning with other words.

Answer (score 4):

*Of* is a hard word to define because English uses it for a lot of different meanings.

> I can't understand this one ,because I can't suppose it means the enviable beauty has a quality of a woman. It looks weird if I simply using the explanation to understand it.

You're close here - think of it meaning *Enviable beauty's qualities are expressed/evident in a woman* or *Enviable beauty's qualities are had by a woman.*

It's possible to use an adjective as a noun to express the notion of a standard or definition of that quality:

> Beauty is defined not just by looks but also grace.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer!I still can not understand it very much. so I made a addition to the question.

Answer (score 4):

A man of honour, a woman of beauty

Such genitive formulas are a literary device, called genitivus qualitatis in Latin grammar. Such genitives are a variant of adjective + noun:

- A man of honour is an honorable man.
- A woman of (great) beauty is a beautiful woman.

In such formulas an attributive adjective is transformed into a noun, placed after the original noun as of-genitive.

In "the worth of music" and "the creaminess of her skin" you have normal genitives as "music" or "skin" are no qualities that correspond to an adjective.